# NodeJS IMAP fetch email body returning [Object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, imap, inbox

I am writing a node.js program that stores incoming email in a database but I am having issues getting the email body. I am using the inbox module. I am also using an outlook account.

```
var inbox = require("inbox");

//I have left out the auth part of the code as it is working correctly.

client.connect();
client.on("connect", function(){
    console.log("Connected!");
        client.openMailbox("GCJA", function(err, messages){
            if(err) throw error;
                client.on("new", function(message){
                
                console.log("New incoming message " + message.title);
                var messageID = message.UID;
                // get the body of an email
                var messageBody = client.createMessageStream(messageID);
                
                console.log("[][RAW MESSAGE START][]"+ messageBody + "{}{RAW MESSAGE END}{}");
 //returnes [Object Object]
```

When I run the program, there are no errors, however it does not return the body of the email but instead [Object Object]. I want to save only the plaintext email in a varible in a form that any human could read and understand.

Comment: `messageBody` is obviously an object, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You should stringify the object:

```
console.log("[][RAW MESSAGE START][]"+ JSON.stringify(messageBody) + "{}{RAW MESSAGE END}{}");
```

Comment: Hello I Tried that but it only returned {"_events":{},"_eventsCount":0}{}

Comment: Because it's a stream

Comment: Then how do I get it into a readable string?

Comment: Did you read the docs? `client.createMessageStream(123).pipe(process.stdout, {end: false});`

Comment: I tried that already and it did not work. I have decided to switch to the Node-Imap module as there is more information on it and I am more familiar with the syntax.